# Unable to modify certain fields in *-meta.xml files

Tags: force.com, ide, metadata, migration-tool

I would like to be able to modify all fields in a specific *-meta.xml file in either the Force.com IDE or the Force.com Migration Toolkit. However, I am unable to set some fields.

For example, I have an Apex Page titled `apexPage`. It has a metadata file called `apexPage.page-meta.xml`. One field in this metadata file is `<availableInTouch>true</availableInTouch>`. When I attempt to change this to `<availableInTouch>false</availableInTouch>` and save this to the server with either the Force.com IDE or the Force.com Migration Toolkit, the field is reverted back to true.

It appears the only way to modify some of these values are through the point-and-click tools. Has anyone found a solution or work around?

Answer (score 0):

For older XML files of existent Apex Pages , If you have API version 29, then your xml would be like

```
<availableInTouch>false</availableInTouch> 
<confirmationTokenRequired>false</confirmationTokenRequired>
```

As your Org would now be on Summer 14 release and supports Version 31.0, use the below xml

```
<isavailableInTouch>false</availableInTouch> 
<isconfirmationTokenRequired>false</confirmationTokenRequired>
```

So try to make the above change and let me know if it helps.

Comment: My org has not been updated to Summer 14 release yet. The highest API version I can set my apex page to is 30. This suggestion did not fix my issue.

Comment: Varun -- I think your ending tags in the second code post need to match the starting tags